# Using theme for making android application throgh Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I am making an android application using titanium studio.I have gone through the kitchensink, where almost all the controls and Components are covered.

What i want to add is , 1> To apply common theme for whole application 2> Define styles for different components. So can any body share their ideas regarding implementation and applying theme and styles to Application for making android app using titanium framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using JSS. More specifically you need to create a `global.jss` file.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Designing+the+User+Interface#DesigningtheUserInterface-SpecifyingGlobalStyles

`JSS` is very easy to use, just assign an `id` to specific elements:

```
#givenId {
    height: 20px;
}
```

or control an entire object and effect all elements of that object

```
label {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: not sure if all of the kinks/issues where resolved with the JSS files yet. I would check JIRA before I went too far and got frustrated. http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @Aaron good point. I get frustrated just trying to use the new JIRA setup thought lol